# Syntax error when using PREPARE Statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I receive a syntax error in stored procedure, when I try to run the PREPARE Statement

The following error showing

```
Syntax error near 'AreaID_var; DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1; END' at line 4

BEGIN
PREPARE stmt1 FROM 'SELECT * FROM Area_TBL WHERE Area_ID = ?';
EXECUTE stmt1 USING AreaID_var;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
END
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL, MS SQL Server or Sybase?

Comment: @jarlh I am using MySQL version 5.7.21

Comment: Shouldn't it be EXECUTE stmt1 USING @AreaID_var;

Comment: @AswaniMadhavan issue solved please add your solution as answer

Comment: Posted as solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change Execute line as follows :-

```
EXECUTE stmt1 USING @AreaID_var;
```